# Is there an equivalent of Rails' each_with_index in an Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Say I have code like this in Angular:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in people">
    {{person.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Referring to a model like this:

```
[
  {name: "Dave"},
  {name: "Martha"}
]
```

Is it possible to generate a DOM like this, where the ids are the array indices of the people?:

```
<ul>
  <li id="person_1>
    Dave
  </li>
  <li id="person_2>
    Martha
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$index` property of [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

e.g.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in people" id="person_{{$index + 1}}">
    {{person.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```